# insert associative array to mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have following data in an Array, I want to store the content of each array index in to mysql table myforum:

```
    Array ( 
            [0] => zero, those players that are trialing for hib team, (hpb's) most of them are like 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg and even worse when they play on uk server's i bet/ 
            [1] => 1998-04-25T213200Z 
            [2] => http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075 
          )
```

mysql Table colums are: content, date, post

```
[0] index value should store in content column,
[1] should store in date column and
[2] should store in post column
```

Comment: Loop through the array,fetch each array element in a local variable and insert it into the mysql table.

Comment: I have tried with the following code but it does not insert any value to mysql database table forum:             <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","sufi","1234");
if (!$con)  { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$xml = simplexml_load_file("boards.xml");
$products[0] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/sioccontent"));
$products[1] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/dctermscreated"));
extract($products); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum (txt_content,txt_date,txt_about) VALUES ('$products[0]','$products[1]','$products[2]')");
?>

Comment: Update your question instead of posting code into the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find anything wrong in your code except escaping the values that you left and may be due to this you are not able to insert the data into table. You can try the below code.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","sufi","1234"); 
 if (!$con) 
     { 
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 

     } 
 mysql_select_db("test", $con); 
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("boards.xml"); 
 $products[0] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/sioccontent")); 
 $products[1] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioctBoardPost/dctermscreated")); 
 extract($products); 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum (txt_content,txt_date,txt_about) 
 VALUES ('".mysql_escape_string($products[0])."','".mysql_escape_string($products[1])."','".mysql_escape_string($products[2])."')"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try With the following example :***

```
<?php
$input_array = array('zero, those players that are trialing for hib team, (hpb\'s) most of them are like 300 -400 pingers? umm..mager lagg and even worse when they play on uk server\'s i bet','1998-04-25T213200Z','http//boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=67075');
$input_array_count= count($input_array);
$coumn_array = array('content','date','post');
$input_array_implode="'".implode("','",$input_array)."'";
$coumn_array_implode="'".implode("','",$coumn_array)."'";
$insert_query=mysql_query("insert into tablename (".$coumn_array_implode.") values (".$input_array_implode.")") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

i think this may help you to resolve your problem.